# How to emit an event with vue-chartjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I use vue js and I display a graph with chartjs. When I click on the graph I want emit an event for get data in parent component. My onClick function works but not the event.
Do you have an idea of my problem ?
Component Line2.vue

```
<script>
import { mixins, Line } from "vue-chartjs";
const { reactiveProp } = mixins;
export default {
  extends: Line, 
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ["options"],
  mounted() {
    const self = this;
    console.log(self);
    this.options.onClick = function (e, tooltipItems) {
      console.log(tooltipItems[0].__ob__); //.logged
      self.$emit("sendIndex", tooltipItems[0]._index);
    };
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

My main component

```
...
    <h1 v-on:sendIndex="getIndexCoord($event)">{{ indexCoord }}</h1>
...
methods: {
    getIndexCoord: function (e) {
      console.log("rrr", e); //Not logged
      this.indexCoord = e;
    },
}
```

Regards

Comment: I resolved my problem with the bus

Comment: The problem is that h1 is not Line2 component and doesn't have sendIndex event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.first you create EventBus.js file
import Vue from 'vue';

```
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

2.In your char.js file code like below

```
import { EventBus } from "../EventBus.js";
import { mixins, Line } from "vue-chartjs";
const { reactiveProp } = mixins;
export default {
  extends: Line, 
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ["options"],
  mounted() {
    const self = this;
    console.log(self);
    this.options.onClick = function (e, tooltipItems) {
      console.log(tooltipItems[0].__ob__); //.logged
      EventBus.$emit("sendIndex", tooltipItems[0]._index);
    };
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  },
};
```

3. where you want to access your data in that file like below

   ```
   import { EventBus } from "../EventBus.js";
   mounted() {

      EventBus.$on('sendIndex', data => {
         console.log(data)
        });

   },
   ```